# git can't find the correct path

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My **initial git commands** look like this

```
01. git init
02. git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/project-2.0.git
03. cd project-2.0
04. mkdir new_subfolder
05. cd .. (came outside of the repo as I need to control/manage from outside the repo)
06. git status
```

After running **git status** all I can see is the ***project-2.0*** folder and nothing else which means git can't understand the correct path.

`On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed) 
project-2.0/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)`

How am I supposed to let git know that I don't want this folder but I actually created a new one inside which needs to be tracked

In short: ***getting the correct path***

Answer (score 1):

You have two git projects here - one in the parent directory of `project-2.0` and one in `project-2.0`.

If you only want the git repo in the project you cloned, delete the `.git` directory in the parent directory of `project-2.0`. Then `git status` from the parent directory should return `Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):`. If you cd into `project-2.0` and run `git status` you should see the untracked directory.

Comment: This happened because you ran `git init`, creating a repository in the current folder, then `git clone`, cloning the inner repository to a subdirectory. In general you would use one or the other, not both.

Comment: @Chris I just removed the .git folder from the parent folder and ran **git status**. 

This is what I got:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/www)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).`

Comment: @pherris I am only trying to control from the parent directory and not from inside the local repo clone. So if I go inside and run the commands then my purpose wouldn't be served.

Comment: If you are trying to control the inner repo from outside, and you don't want to `cd` into it, then you can generally use `--git-dir=project-2.0/.git` e.g., `git --git-dir=project-2.0/.git status`.